# Prevent that TrueCrypt gets Administrator rights

Tags: security, password, sudo, encryption, root

If I try to open a TrueCrypt drive, TrueCrypt asks me for my administrator-password (also when I am a normal user).
I know, that i can prevent this password-asking by editing the sudoers file = giving TrueCrypt general administrator privileges.
But in my eyes, giving TrueCrypt generally administrator privileges is a security risk.

So my question is: How can I edit TrueCrypt, in the way, that it not wants administrator privileges anymore, to mount a TrueCrypt volume.

(I do not understand why TrueCrypt wants/needs administrator-privileges to mount a volume/filesystem. Because if I put an USB Stick in my Computer, it gets mountet without additional administrator privileges. So why shell TrueCrypt need more privileges?)

I use Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You or someone else would probably need to fork it with that function removed if it's not necessary. If it's making calls to kernel land then you will need to use the sudoers file change that you mentioned.